# When using vb.net I need to join 2 datatables to just 1 gridview

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I have been searching through a lot of different forums, but havent found the help I am looking for, so here we go.

First of all I should inform you that I am well aware, that 1 solution could be to do a SQL join in my sql statement, however this is not so easy as I am using 2 different tables from 2 different databases. So I am interesting in hearing in another solution.

As it is now, I have made 2 queries, and made 2 datatables, and 2 gridviews. 
I have succeeded in binding the data in the 2 gridviews, and now I kinda want to "merge" them based on 1 column that they share.

How to do this in VB.net I don't know.

Basically I have 1 table in the database `dbo_db_Test_Palle` on the server `OKPalle`. From this I take the following columns and put into my datatable dt and bind to gridview 1.

```
| Name | ID | Organisation |
```

In another datatable (dt2) from `dbo_db_Test_Palle2` from the server `NOTokPalle` I take the following columns and put into dt2, and bind to Gridview 2.

```
| Nickname | City  | Hobby | ID
```

What I would like to show in just one `GridView` is:

```
| Name | ID | Organisation | Nickname | City  | Hobby |
```

So basically I wish to add `City` and `Hobby` columns, from `dt2` to `dt`, where the posts with ID matches (others I just leave blank).

I really hope someone out here can help me.

Comment: Hi! I don't get why is not easy doing a SQL Join. You could use a View in the other DB and a SP on your main DB to return this table. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: Hi Engerlost! I am also looking into the SQL join, however as I access 2 different databases I need to establish connections with different users ..how would I go around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, but it's been a while since I've done this, you might need to hack around with it a little.

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    ds.Tables.Add(dt2)
    ds.Relations.Add("rel", dt2.Columns("ID"), dt.Columns("ID"), False)
    dt.Columns.Add("Nickname", GetType(System.String), "Parent.Nickname")
    dt.Columns.Add("City", GetType(System.String), "Parent.City")
    dt.Columns.Add("Hobby", GetType(System.String), "Parent.Hobby")
```

Comment: I tried out your code and got the following Error: (I changed ID to BrugerID) -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Cannot find relation 0. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find relation 0. Line 133: ds.Relations.Add("rel", dt.Columns("BrugerID"), dt2.Columns("BrugerID"))

Comment: Oh, yeah, it established the parent-child relationship in reverse. I've edited the code above to swap the position of the two tables in the Relations.Add line.

Comment: You my good friend, are amazing! Thankyou so much :)!! Now I will move out from my test page and do this on a larger scale! Thankyou so much once again:)! 

Have a nice day good Sir.

Br
Vildgut

Comment: However now I get this error message: 

"This constraint cannot be enabled as not all values have corresponding parent values."

I find it hard to figure out what causes it? I have looked in my testDB, and they all have an ID and the values I wish to show, it works if I search them out one at a time. If I want to mach all at once, it doesnt work :/

Comment: Try adding a ",False" at the end of that same line. You might want to read up on these classes and methods on MSDN.

Comment: Ty Clweeks, I also found out about the False value, didnt quite solve my problem, but for now I will read some more on it :) Thankyou for your help!

Comment: Yeah, at this point, I'd have to do your reading for you -- we're outside the domain of stuff that I just know off-hand. Hopefully we got you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Yep, I will also benefit more from reading it myself, and you sure pointed me the right direction. 

Thankyou very much! Have a good day :)